# verification of installation of skbio

Tags: python, windows, skbio

I installed the Scikit-bio python module in Windows 10.
After installation, I verified the installation by running `python -m skbio.test`

I got the following result (end part of message)

```
ERROR AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/lib/site-packages/skbio/io/tests/test_util.py::TestWriteBufferedReader::test_open_gzip - PermissionE...
```

ERROR AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/lib/site-packages/skbio/io/tests/test_util.py::TestWriteBufferedReader::test_open_gzip_encoding - Pe...
================================ 220 failed, 2324 passed, 30 skipped, 4856 warnings, 8 errors in 318.73s (0:05:18) ================================

It seems that something are not installed well..Doesn't my installation have any problem?
Hope for answer
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed it using pip, try uninstalling it and using conda instead, as per its pypi.org instructions. It could also be an issue with your OS. Also, try verifying numpy is installed.